# org.hibernate.HibernateException: two open sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I am newbie in hibernate technology and I am struggling with the following exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a
>   collection with two open sessions

I get this when I try to make a new line into my DB.

My setting/code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
     "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Paramètres de connexion à la base de données -->
        <!-- <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> -->
        <!-- <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bh</property> -->
        <!-- <property name="connection.username">root</property> -->
        <!-- <property name="connection.password"></property> -->
        <!-- <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> -->

        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/projetForum</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">esct</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Comportement pour la conservation des tables -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Activation : affichage en console, commentées et formatées -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

        <!-- Fichiers à mapper -->
        <mapping class="com.forum.beans.Utilisateur" />
        <mapping class="com.forum.beans.Topic" />
        <mapping class="com.forum.beans.Post" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

A session holder:

```
package com.forum.utils;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtils {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // Crée une unique instance de la SessionFactory à partir de
    // hibernate.cfg.xml
    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Problème de configuration : "
                    + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    // Renvoie une session Hibernate
    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

Code that causes the error :

```
Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            s = HibernateUtils.getSession();
            tx = s.beginTransaction();
            s.persist(u);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: You haven't specified how you are getting u object. My feel is you are loading it via hibernate and its still attached to another session.

Comment: easies to post here and get a quick fix for that, than if you meet again a strange behavior than post again and again. If you want to learn: go and check which are those cases, when the Singleton ( design pattern) constructs 2 objectr or more. Almost sure one of those cases you met you now. Pls don't tell me a Singleton is Singleton because only 1 is from him. It should be only one, but I can write a code, which makes 2 of those :)

Comment: It seems like you are persisting an object that's already bound to another session, try to use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() instead of sessionFactory.openSession() and see if it works properly, are you using the OpenSessionInViewFilter filter?

Comment: Do you close the session anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Hibernate, what I can see from your code:

Instead of using

```
openSession()
```

try

```
getSession()
```

Similar issue solved at [URL](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?26782-Illegal-attempt-to-associate-a-collection-with-two-open-sessions)